# Marking special nodes that traverses a certain length in a graph to fill up every node

Tags: algorithm, graph

So I am working on a problem where you have one graph, where all edges has a certain weight to it. Now the algorithm is supposed to select certain node(s) in the graph and the selected nodes must be able to traverse/span through all other nodes within a certain total weight. The output should be the minimum number of selected nodes and the position of the selected nodes (it doesn't matter which position it outputs as long as it is the minimum number of selected nodes)

I have thought of a couple simple solutions but neither of them seem too good so far.

1. Brute force by trying out every node. The algorithm will start with one selected node and then try every combination of selected nodes, which then loops through every other non-selected nodes and check if they are all within range. If not it increases one extra selected node and repeats the same process.
2. The algorithm makes a list of subgraph that can be traversed with 1 selected node at every node position. Then attempt to puzzle fit the subgraphs so that it re-creates the original graph and if it succeeds that would be the solution.

As an example, here's a picture of a grid as the graph.

[image]

The weights of every edge in this grid is 1, and each selected node can travel through a total weights of 2.

I'm not too familiar with graph problems so if there is a similar question out there or if anyone can provide any help with the solution that would be great!

Comment: How big is your graph (number of nodes/edges)? `total weight` which means the total distance to all nodes that node `x` is covered or just the maximum distance from this node `x` to one other?

Comment: There is no limit to the number of nodes/edges/weights although the total won't be that big. From the image you'll see that each colored node is the selected node, and each colored edges are the paths that each selected node can traverse to, and the goal is to cover all nodes in the graph with the least number of selected nodes. This is a simplified example and not all edges may have the same weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can get rid of the edge weights by simply making an edge between two nodes if they are within the distance limit. Then you need to find a subset of the nodes such that each node is either selected or neighbor of a selected node. This is known as the [Dominating Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) problem. Unfortunately, it is NP-hard, so typically it is solved heuristically or using Integer Linear Programming. It might be possible to take advantage of certain properties of the input, but it is hard to tell without knowing more about what they look like.